# refactor jquery code to one line of code

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
$('#csv_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("disabled");
$('#excel_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("disabled");
$('#delete_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("disabled");
```

Is it possible simplify this code to one line of code?

Comment: Sounds like a test question to me. :-)

Comment: .prop() should be used to set disabled property if using jquery 1.6+

Comment: May I suggest `attr('disabled',true)` (or `prop('disabled',true)`) to make an input element disabled?

Comment: can create a function. I would not recommend disabled attribute as in IE7 it will create grey fonts if you later choose to display it. by removing disabled class from css. 

I would recommend just do it using addClass do not use disabled. or you can directly use hide actually. use functions in this case you can create a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can separate multiple selectors with commas:

```
$('#csv_button,#excel_button,#delete_button').prop('disabled', true).addClass("disabled");
```

Or you could apply the same class to all 3 elements and use a class selector:

```
$('.disabled-button').prop('disabled', true).addClass("disabled");
```

Comment: Thank you the first reply is correct and is workinf fine for me :). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#csv_button,#excel_button,#delete_button').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do:

```
  $("[id$='button']").prop('disabled', true).addClass("disabled");
```

This will return all elements with id ending with 'button'.

More information on jquery selectors can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).